# Knowing when to delete associated user data from a std::map<void *, ...>

Tags: c++, dictionary, std

I have a map of addresses that allows me to store arbitrary data with objects.  Basically, a library I'm writing has a templated function that winds up storing arbitrary data with objects.

```
std::map<void *, MyUserData>
```

This works, until the object passed in is destroyed, leaving its user data in the map.  I want the associated user data to be removed as well, so I need to somehow listen for the destructor of the passed in object,

Some example code that illustrates the problem:

```
#include <map>
#include <memory>


struct MyUserData
{
        int someNum;
};

std::map<void *, MyUserData> myMap;

template <typename T>
registerObject<T>(const std::shared_ptr<T> & _object)
{
        static inc = 0;

        myMap[(void *)&_object->get()].someNum = inc++;
}

struct MyObject
{
        int asdf;
};

int main(int _argc, char ** _argv)
{
        auto obj = std::make_shared<MyObject>();
        obj->asdf = 5;

        registerObject(obj);

        obj = 0;

        //The user data is still there.  I want it to be removed at this point.
}
```

My current solution is to set a custom deleter on the shared_ptr.  This signals me for when the object's destructor is called, and tells me when to remove the associated user data.  Unfortunately, this requires my library to create the shared_ptr, as there is no "set_deleter" function.  It must be initialized in the constructor.

```
mylib::make_shared<T>(); //Annoying!
```

I could also have the user manually remove their objects:

```
mylib::unregister<T>(); //Equally annoying!
```

My goal is to be able to lazily add objects without any prior-registration.

In a grand summary, I want to detect when the object is deleted, and know when to remove its counterpart from the `std::map`.

Any suggestions?

P.S. Should I even worry about leaving the user data in the map?  What are the chances that an object is allocated with the same address as a previously deleted object?  (It would end up receiving the same user data as far as my lib is concerned.)

EDIT: I don't think I expressed my problem very well initially.  Rewritten.

Comment: ok can you please post some code sample? Which is being deleted the map key, the object stored? are all object stored of the same type? do you control that type?

Comment: Use **intrusive** containers or **smart pointers**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From you code example, it looks like the external interface is

```
template <typename T>
registerObject<T>(const std::shared_ptr<T> & _object);
```

I assume there is a get-style API somewhere. Let's call this `getRegisteredData`. (It could be internal.)

Within the confines of the question, I'd use `std::weak_ptr<void>` instead of `void*`, as `std::weak_ptr<T>` can tell when there are no more "strong references" to the object around, but won't prevent the object from being deleted by maintaining a reference.

```
std::map<std::weak_ptr<void>, MyUserData> myMap;

template <typename T>
registerObject<T>(const std::shared_ptr<T> & _object)
{
    static inc = 0;

    Internal_RemoveDeadObjects();

    myMap[std::weak_ptr<void>(_object)].someNum = inc++;
}

template <typename T>
MyUserData getRegisteredData(const std::shared_ptr<T> & _object)
{
    Internal_RemoveDeadObjects();
    return myMap[std::weak_ptr<void>(_object)];
}

void Internal_RemoveDeadObjects()
{
    auto iter = myMap.cbegin();
    while (iter != myMap.cend())
    {
        auto& weakPtr = (*iter).first; 
        const bool needsRemoval = !(weakPtr.expired());

        if (needsRemoval)
        {
            auto itemToRemove = iter;
            ++iter;
            myMap.erase(itemToRemove);
        }
        else
        {
            ++iter;
        }
    }
}
```

Basically, `std::weak_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr` collaborate and `std::weak_ptr` can detect when there are no more `std::shared_ptr` references to the object in question. Once that is the case, we can remove the ancillary data from `myMap`. I'm using the two interfaces to `myMap`, your `registerObject` and my `getRegisteredData` as convenient places to call `Internal_RemoveDeadObjects` to perform the clean up.

Yes, this walks the entirety of `myMap` every time a new object is registered or the registered data is requested. Modify as you see fit or try a different design.

You ask "Should I even worry about leaving the user data in the map? What are the chances that an object is allocated with the same address as a previously deleted object?" In my experience, decidedly non-zero, so don't do this. :-)

Comment: So I should check for old user data every time the list is accessed?  In that case, I might as well not use a map, but rather a linked list or vector.

Answer (score 1):

I'd add a deregister method, and make the user deregister their objects.  With the interface as given, where you're stripping the type away, I can't see a way to check for the ref-count, and C++ doesn't provide a way to check whether memory has been deleted or not.

Comment: Well, if I required the objects to be shared_ptr's (which I'm fine with), I could store a weak_ptr and therefore be able to tell if the object has been deleted.  Unfortunately, I don't know *when* it's deleted.

Comment: The best you'd be able to do at that point is periodically run a collection.

Answer (score 1):

I thought about it for a while and this is as far as I got:

```
#include <memory>
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>

using namespace std;

struct MyUserData
{
    int someNum;
};

map<void *, MyUserData> myMap;

template<class T>
class my_shared_ptr : public shared_ptr<T>
{
public:
    my_shared_ptr() { }

    my_shared_ptr(const shared_ptr<T>& s)  : shared_ptr<T>(s) { }

    my_shared_ptr(T* t) : shared_ptr<T>(t) {  }

    ~my_shared_ptr()
    { 
        if (unique()) 
        {           
            myMap.erase(get());
        }
    }

};


template <typename T>
void registerObject(const my_shared_ptr<T> & _object)
{
    static int inc = 0;

    myMap[(void *)_object.get()].someNum = inc++;
}

struct MyObject
{
    int asdf;
};

int main() 
{   
    {   
        my_shared_ptr<MyObject> obj2;

        {
            my_shared_ptr<MyObject> obj = make_shared<MyObject>();
            obj->asdf = 5;
            registerObject(obj);

            obj2 = obj;

            assert(myMap.size() == 1); 
        }

        /* obj is destroyed, but obj2 still points to the data */
        assert(myMap.size() == 1);
    }

    /* obj2 is destroyed, nobody points to the data */
    assert(myMap.size() == 0);

}
```

Note however that it wouldn't work if you wrote `obj = nullptr;` , or `obj.reset()`, since the object isn't destroyed in those cases (no destructor called). Also, you can't use auto with this solution.

Also, be careful not to call (void *)&_object.get() like you were doing. If I'm not terribly wrong, by that statement you're actually taking the address of the temporary that _object.get() returns, and casting it to void. That address, however, becomes invalid instantly after.

Comment: It doesn't actually matter if that becomes invalid.  It's only used as a unique key.  I don't care about the data at that point.

Comment: Concerning the solution itself, wouldn't that involve having my own my_shared_ptr<T> factory?

Answer (score 0):

You can just do

```
map.erase(map.find(obj));
delete obj;
obj = 0;
```

this will call the destructor for your user data and remove it from the map.

Or you could make your own manager:

```
class Pointer;
extern std::map<Pointer,UserData> data;
class Pointer
{
private:
    void * pointer;
public:
    //operator ()
    void * operator()()
    {
        return pointer;
    }
    //operator =
    Pointer& operator= (void * ptr)
    {
        if(ptr == 0)
        {
            data.erase(data.find(pointer));
            pointer = 0;
        }
        else
            pointer = ptr;
        return *this;
    }
    Pointer(void * ptr)
    {
        pointer = ptr;
    }
    Pointer()
    {
        pointer = 0;
    }
    ~Pointer(){}
};

struct UserData
{
    static int whatever;
    UserData(){}
};

std::map<Pointer,UserData> data;

int main()
{
    data[Pointer(new UserData())].whatever++;
    data[Pointer(new UserData())].whatever++;
    data[Pointer(new UserData())].whatever++;
    data[Pointer(new UserData())].whatever++;
    Pointer x(new UserData());
    data[x].whatever;
    x = 0;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The map isn't public like this.  I don't want the user to manually have to do this.  I'm writing a library, you see.

Comment: Is the map accessible from the MyUserData structure?

Comment: Which data structure?  The only "public" function in the library is `registerObject()`, which technically only exists here for sake of example.

Comment: I could only suggest you to create an "unregisterobject" function which would contain the above code, but for the "sake" of examples see [this](http://sscce.org/) :p

Comment: or just use std::shared_ptr and the object will be destroyed when there are no more references to it. In the destructor of MyUserData you could put code which removes it from the map.

Comment: This is pretty much the reason that shared_ptr exists.

Comment: I have 1300 lines of heavily templated enable_if'd meta code.  In fact, these references are being passed as heavy userdata into a stack-based programming language called Lua, and they're indexed by pointer there.  In other words, the `std::map` itself doesn't even exist.  I'm confident my actual code would just confuse everybody, and limit the population willing to answer my question.

Comment: What do you mean this is why shared_ptr exists?  Do you understand the problem?  I'm associating arbitrary data with objects of any type.

Comment: but a SSCCEE of your actual could would be targeted by somebody who knows what he is doing, now we're trying to fix a different issue. if the map doesn't exist use delete to deallocate the data. overload the =0 operator and check for = 0.. anything.. it just hurts my brain I can't come up with anything if your data doesn't reside in a map yet your code is simplified using that XD

Comment: I have posted code with the equivalent problem.  The issue is exactly the same here as it is in my code.

Comment: The trouble is, now any object passed in must inherit from Pointer, which is a no-no.  That, or, you're saying I should use my own shared_ptr equivalent, which I also don't want.

Comment: please.. SSCCE, no matter how complex your example is, there's always someone who will understand it ;f I'm out of ideas (for now)

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a job for... `boost::intrusive` (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/intrusive.html)! I don't think the current interface will work exactly as it stands though. I'll try to work out a few more details a little later as I get a chance.

Comment: Please, do explain further.